# Environment record method CreateMutableBinding in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

## About Environment Record

At  [**sec. 10.2**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.2) said

> An Environment Record records the identifier bindings that are created
>   within the scope of its associated Lexical Environment.

and at [**sec 10.2.1**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.2.1) said that

> There are two kinds of Environment Record values used in this
>   specification: declarative environment records and object environment
>   records. Declarative environment records are used to define the effect
>   of ECMAScript language syntactic elements such as
>   FunctionDeclarations, VariableDeclarations, and Catch clauses that
>   directly associate identifier bindings with ECMAScript language
>   values. Object environment records are used to define the effect of
>   ECMAScript elements such as Program and WithStatement that associate
>   identifier bindings with the properties of some object.

Please, check my understanding:

Thus, if we consider the following code snippet:

```
function foo(){
    var bar={prop:'prop'}
    var test_bar=bar;
    test_test_bar={p:'p'};
}
```

corresponding **declarative environment record** will be contain bindings `bar-->{prop:'prop'}, test_bar-->{prop:'prop'}, test_test_bar-->{p:'p'}`. Is it true?

And one **question**:

Is it true that for all syntactic elements there exists only one `environment record`. This is either declarative or object environment record.

## About Absctract method of environment record

[**Sec 10.2.1**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.2.1http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.2.1) contains info about abstract method of `environment record`.

Method:

`CreateMutableBinding(N, D)`

Purpose:

> Create a new mutable binding in an environment record. The String
>   value N is the text of the bound name. If the optional Boolean
>   argument D is true the binding is may be subsequently deleted.

So **question** is the following:

What does mean **bound name** in this method's purpose? Is it pair of `Identifier-->variable` such as `bar-->{prop:'prop'}` in my example above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> consider the following code snippet:
>
> ```
> function foo(){
>     var bar={prop:'prop'}
>     var test_bar=bar;
>     test_test_bar={p:'p'};
> }
> ```
>
> corresponding declarative environment record will be contain bindings
>   `bar-->{prop:'prop'}, test_bar-->{prop:'prop'},
>   test_test_bar-->{p:'p'}`. Is it true?

Nearly. It does contain `foo`, `bar` and `test_bar` (with their values). The environment record is part of an lexical environment that has a pointer to its "outer lexical environment" that holds the record with the global variables like `test_test_bar`.

> And one question: Is it true that for all syntactic elements there exists only one environment record.

No. Environment records don't have much to do with syntactic elements, they are created dynamically at runtime within the execution contexts. There might as well be multiple environment records alive for the same code element, say in a closure. What the spec said is: "*environment records are used to define **the effect** of ECMAScript language syntactic elements*". They represent the structures that are used to explain what should happen when a syntax element is executed.

> What does mean *bound name* in this method's purpose? Is it pair of `Identifier-->variable` such as `bar-->{prop:'prop'}` in my example above?

Nah, it's only the `Identifier`. The pair of identifier and value is called *binding*. To assign a value to an identifier, you use the `SetMutableBinding(bound_name, value, strict_flag)` method.